# How to withdraw dollars from MtGox to dwolla?

Tags: web-services, bitcoin, dwolla

I am trying to use the [following API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API#0.2Fwithdraw.php) to withdraw dollars from MtGox to DWOLLA. The code I already implemented successfully handles authentication. From the write-up it seems to me that I need to post something like that:

```
group1=DWUSD&btca=XXX-XXX-XXXX&amount=XXX.XX
```

However, I'm getting an error in response, which says:

```
{"error":"Amount too low or invalid Dwolla account"}
```

Anyone here has an idea what the proper calling convention is? I am a little hesitant to play around, fear the money will get lost if I do something incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the resolution by examining HTML on MtGox site. Must use `dwaccount=` instead of `btca=` when withdrawing to dwolla